# MS SQL Table joins

Tags: sql-server, join

My database has a field called `record_num` that is used in every table. Every row has a `record_num` column regardless of the table the row belongs to.

I have about 5 tables where which table is used depends upon what the input is (error, recipe, alarms etc). Each entry gets its own unique `record_num`. I want to join all my tables to see if there is any gaps in my record_num to be sure there are no bugs in the software generating the info. Join seems to only combine like values. I want to join all of them to be sure the sequence is correct.

For example, if the `alarm` table has record_num value 433 and the `error` has record_num  432 and 434, I want to join to get 432,433,434 so I can check the sequence for gaps (missing entries).

How would I do this?

Comment: Even if you don't find any gaps in the numbering it doesn't mean there are no bugs.  Joining them is a bit pointless but you can do it using OUTER JOIN's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `UNION`, not a join. Combine this with a few other techniques and you can find any gaps in one query:

```
with seq as (
    select record_num 
    from [error]
    union
    select record_num 
    from alarm
    order by record_num
), 
seq2 as (
     select record_num, row_number() over (order by record_num) as ordinal
     from seq
)
select s1.record_num
from seq2 s1
inner join seq2 s2 on s2.ordinal = s1.ordinal + 1 and s2.record_num <> s1.record_num + 1
```

or with the LAG keyword:

```
with seq as (
    select record_num 
    from [error]
    union
    select record_num 
    from alarm
    order by record_num
), 
lags as (
     select record_num, lag(record_num, 1, record_num -1) over (order by record_num) as prior_record
     from seq
)
select record_num
from lags 
where record_num - prior_record > 1
```

You also need to fix the broken database schema. A `record_num` field common to all tables is okay, but splitting like data across 5 different tables is not okay, and allowing an outside system to generate your IDs is not okay. You the identity feature or a sequence that's built into Sql Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know the set up of the database is off but its a new addition to our R+D team for some internal life tests on a couple products. I am working to get the changes made to make it easier and more efficient. FYI I would not have set it up in the manner chosen. Thank you again